# HTML canvas doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

i'm working on a map thing where several waypoints are shown. Now they should be connected with a simple stroke to show the path which i try using a  tag.

The Canvas is set, the drawing happens in a javascript that evaluates the position of where to draw and strokes a path. The problem is that the canvas is not shown, but all the functions called in the script are properly written and called.

The html-code is below:

```
<body>
    <div id="controller">
        <div id="zeichenfenster">
            <span id="maps"></span>
            <span id="objects"></span>
            <canvas id="canvas" height="1000px" width="2000px"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

...and here's the javascript:

```
function connectDrawables(drawable1, drawable2, id) {

    connections[id] = "" + drawable1 + "|" + drawable2;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 1000);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5.0;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";

    for(var k in connections) {

            var string = connections[k];
            var sub = string.split("|");

            var element1 = document.getElementById(sub[0]);
            var element2 = document.getElementById(sub[1]);

            var x1 = 0.0 + parseFloat((element1.style.marginLeft).replace("px", "")) + 8;
            var y1 = 0.0 + parseFloat((element1.style.marginTop).replace("px", "")) + 7;
            var x2 = 0.0 + parseFloat((element2.style.marginLeft).replace("px", "")) + 5;
            var y2 = 0.0 + parseFloat((element2.style.marginTop).replace("px", "")) + 4;                
            //alert("ID: " + id + "\nElement1: " + drawable1 + " x1: " + x1 + " y1: " + y1 + "\nElement2: " + drawable2 + " x2: " + x2 + " y2: " + y2);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
            ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
            ctx.stroke();

    }

}
```

drawable1 and 2 are the id's of the waypoints, connections is an associative array, id is the unique id.

If i place the canvas at the html-code "above" the other tags there's just one great white space, but the drawing doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: did you style the svg to have a stroke-width > 0 ?

Comment: it's an swt-browser, it supports html 5 and the canvas stroke worked once

Comment: Just took a quick look at it, for me it looks like you're drawing white lines on a white canvas?

Comment: yeah, you're right, the color is indeed white, but changing it to black doesn't help. The canvas itself is transparent so the image in the background should be visible and also the white lines drawn

Comment: Could we see more of your code, ie where is the connectables object created? Where are the elements' margins set? is the function connectDrawables being called before the canvas is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

what about "ctx.closePath()" in the end??

```
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: ctx.closePath() is not needed, ctx.stroke() ends all open drawings

Comment: @LordLeicester This is not correct, stroke() doesn't close anything.